# How do you algebraically demostrate that $f(x)=x^3-x$ is not a one to one function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics

So, I'm trying to prove that the function its not one to one, but I'm stuck:

$f(x_1)=f(x_2) \to x_1=x_2$ then is a one to one

So

$ x_1^3-x_1=x_2^3-x_2 $

$x_1^3-x_2^3-x_1+x_2=0$

$(x_1-x_2)(x_1^2+x_1x_2+x_2^2)-(x_1-x_2)=0$

$(x_1-x_2)(x_1^2+x_1x_2+x_2^2-1)=0$

Which is true if $x_1=x_2$ but how do I go about proving that is not a one to one function?

Comment: $f(0)=f(1)$ so $f$ is not one-to-one.

Comment: Clearly the best answer for this particular question. @KaviRamaMurthy More generally, the one-to-one property of real continuous functions boils down to strict monotonicity. If the function is also differentiable and the derivative changes sign, then it is not one-to-one.

Comment: Thank you so much @KaviRamaMurthy, I was just trying to do a more general method, but I guess we don't need to overcomplicate things.

Comment: @OmarMunguía: being one-to-one means that *for every $x_1$ and $x_2$* some property is satisfied. The negation of the definition is that there exists a pair $x_1$ $x_2$ that does not satisfy the property. So it is sufficient to find such a pair.

Answer (score 1):

This is also true if

$$x_1^2+x_1\cdot x_2+x_2^2-1=0$$

With the p-q formula, treating $x_1$ as the variable, we get

$$x_1=-\frac{x_2}{2} + \sqrt{\frac{x_2^2}{4} -x_2^2+1}=-\frac{x_2}{2} + \sqrt{1-\frac{3x_2^2}{4}}$$
and
$$x_1=-\frac{x_2}{2} + \sqrt{1-\frac{3x_2^2}{4}}$$

Thus, there are solutions when $x_1 \neq x_2$ and you are not one to one.

Answer (score 1):

You can assume $f$ to be one to one and show contradictions.

$\exists \ 0,1\in\mathbb R$ such that $0^3-0=0$ and $1^3-1=0$

which contradicts $f$ being a one to one function. Hence, $f$ is not one to one.